# JSON HTML conversion to string keeps "\n" every line break

Tags: java, android, html, json

I am writing a code for an application that retrieves data from a WordPress website that aims for a youth movement.
I already installed Rest API, and when I retrieve the JSON data of posts, it works great in its HTML form, but when I convert it:

`String content2 = Html.fromHtml(content).toString();` 
it does break lines properly, but it keeps "\n" each line break...
I am searching for a solution in this website and online for 2 days, but still, haven't managed to solve it, I truly don't know why is it happening...
this is my DownLoadJson class code:

```
 public class DownLoadJson extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<GamesLibrary> >
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        p=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Activities Library","loading, please wait...",true);
        p.setCancelable(true);
        p.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        p.setMessage("Loading...");
        p.show();

        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<GamesLibrary> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<GamesLibrary> data=null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
        URL url = null;
        try
        {
            data = getJsondata(params[0]);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        return data;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<GamesLibrary> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result!=null)
        {
            gamesLibraryAdapter=new GamesLibraryAdapter(MainActivity.this,0,0,result);
            lv.setAdapter(gamesLibraryAdapter);
            p.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my  getJsonData Class:

```
public ArrayList<GamesLibrary> getJsondata(String strurl)
{
    ArrayList<GamesLibrary>arrayList=new ArrayList<GamesLibrary>();
    String line="";
    String res="";
    InputStream in=null;
    try
    {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
        URL url = null;
        try
        {
            URL myURL = new URL(strurl);
            URLConnection ucon = myURL.openConnection();
            in = ucon.getInputStream();
            Log.d("Negev", in.toString());
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("asaf",e.getMessage());
        }


        BufferedReader x=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"iso-8859-1"));

        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("");

        String l="";

        while((l=x.readLine())!=null)
        {
            sb.append(l+"\n");
        }

        in.close();
        x.close();
        line=sb.toString();


        try
        {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(line);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {

                Log.d("asaf","try json"+i);
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String date = json_data.getString("title");
                String content = json_data.getString("content");
                String content2 = Html.fromHtml(content).toString();
                String id = json_data.getString("id");
                String slug = json_data.getString("slug");
                GamesLibrary gamesLibrary= new GamesLibrary(Integer.valueOf(id),date,content2,slug);
                arrayList.add(gamesLibrary);
                Log.d("ff",content2 );

            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {

        }
        return arrayList;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return null;
}
```

I should mention that the classes fully succeed at retrieving data, and the data they are meant to, but the conversion to HTML doesn't work well...
Thank you!

Update: I realized I didn't show any example of how the text looks like:
before, it looks lie an ordinary HTML, but after it looks like that: (Line breaks DO word)

```html
 Bla Bla
\nBla Bla Bla BLa
\nBla
```

Even though it skips a line, it still shows "\n"...

Comment: what is error you are getting

Comment: I don't get any error, except the fact that the text in the listview looks like this: Hi, my name is[line break] \nBla Bla.

Comment: Hello @NegNeg64, can you post the json ?